# Integers representation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Define recurrent type of `Integers` representation to work like so:

```
data Integers = Zero | Next Integers | Prev Integers
```

and make this representation, the instance of class Num, it means that You should can use `(+), (*), (==), abs, signum, show` on `Integers`

Till now i defined sth like this:

```
data Integers = Zero | Integers Int deriving (Show)

next :: Integers -> Integers
next Zero = Integers 1
next (Integers a) = Integers a + Integers 1

prev :: Integers -> Integers
prev (Integers 1) = Zero
prev (Integers a) = Integers a - Integers 1

instance Eq Integers where  
    Zero == Zero = True
    Integers a == Integers b = a == b  
    _ == _ = False

instance Num Integers where
    Integers a + Integers b = Integers (a + b)
    Integers a - Integers b = Integers (a - b)
    Integers a * Integers b = Integers (a * b)
    abs (Integers a) = Integers (abs a)
    signum (Integers a) = Integers (signum a)
    fromInteger a = Integers (fromInteger a)
```

But it doesn't fit the `data Integers = Zero | Next Integers | Prev Integers` expectations

Comment: Can you implements just the natural numbers with `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` ?

Comment: I just don't know how to implement it with this "Succ" notation -> as in my question (Next/Prev)

Comment: Why have you used `data Integers = Zero | Integers Int` rather than the definition given to you?

Comment: Could you maybe make an attempt at implementing the naturals in this way, as Chris Kuklewicz suggests? Just do the type and addition first, and I'm sure you'll soon see how to do multiplication and `show` (once you have the hang of the naturals, the integers will be easier). So where to begin? Well, begin by asking yourself what a natural number is. Answer: It's either zero, or the successor of some other natural number. Great. And if you add a natural number n to zero, you get n. So you only need to know how to add non-zero naturals... hint: a non-zero is a successor of another natural...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data Integers = Zero | Next Integers | Prev Integers
```

I'm going to show you `+`, the rest should be easy enough.

```
Zero + y = y
x + Zero = x
```

Well, that was easy!

Oh. There are some other cases.

Still, we've handled all the `Zero` cases, so now we only have to deal with `Prev` and `Next`. They're opposites of each other, aren't they? So if we're given one of each, they'll cancel each other out.

```
Next x + Prev y = x + y
Prev x + Next y = x + y
```

Now we only have to worry about the cases where the numbers we're given both have the same sign.

```
Next x + Next y = Next (Next (x + y))
Prev x + Prev y = Prev (Prev (x + y))
```

(These last two equations are not the most efficient implementation, but they are straightforward to understand.)

And we're done defining `+`.

Some of the other functions are easier, some are harder (and should reuse some of the easier functions), but they all involve pattern matching on the/either/both parameter(s) and doing the appropriate thing. And mostly they involve recursion, usually inescapable at some level when given a recursive data structure.